# VBA Writing Function Outcome into active and offset cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I created a function which has two outcomes: t_final and q_final (t means time, q means the rate of production).

When I use the first coding in VBA without explicitly mention the cell and just have one outcome (t_final), the result appears. But I need two outcomes and write them in a consecutive cell.

The first code gives me the calculated result. The second one only gives me #value.

```
 Function t_final(qi, Di, b, q_limit)
'qi: initial rate
'Di: initial decline rate
'b:  decline exponent
'q_limit : economic limit for rate
'Nominal decline is the instantaneous decline rate
    Dim i, t, q_final
    i = 1
    Do
    t = i * 30
    q_final = arpsrate(qi, Di, b, t)
    i = i + 1
    t_final = t
    Loop Until q_final < q_limit

 End Function
'The second code is the same as the first one with additional:
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = t_final
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = q_final
```

Thank you for paying interest to my problem!

Comment: A function called as a UDF cannot update the worksheet except by returning a value (or array of values)  If you need to return multiple values then return an array and enter the formula over 3 cells using Ctrl+Shift+Enter  See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value and https://www.exceltip.com/custom-functions-in-vba/create-vba-function-to-return-array.html

Comment: Sir, did you mean multiple values for an outcome (means t_final in terms of an index)? Actually I need only two single outcomes which are t_final and q_final itself.

Comment: You could add a fifth input parameter, with which you determine if `t_final` or `q_final` needs to be returned.  Then upon using the function you can determine which value is returned.

Comment: So nothing is returned to the cell containing the UDF formula?  You would need to return something there...

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, you need to return an array from your UDF if you need multiple outputs.

```vb
Function t_final(qi, Di, b, q_limit)
    'qi: initial rate
    'Di: initial decline rate
    'b:  decline exponent
    'q_limit : economic limit for rate
    'Nominal decline is the instantaneous decline rate
    Dim i, t, q_final, t_f
    i = 1
    Do
        t = i * 30
        q_final = arpsrate(qi, Di, b, t)
        i = i + 1
        t_f = t
    Loop Until q_final < q_limit

    t_final = Array(t_f, q_final)
 End Function
```

Then use like this

```
{=t_final([arguments here])}
```

entered over two cells (across) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Maybe worth noting that CSE isn't needed depending on the version?

Comment: @BigBen - my version doesn't have that yet but if the OP does then https://exceloffthegrid.com/dynamic-arrays-and-vba-user-defined-functions-udfs/ covers the topic

Comment: FWIW, for users who do have the latest version of Excel, this UDF will work. Just enter it in one cell, and don't use CSE.  It will Spill into the adjacent column